# Biblatex: displaying url dates in bibliography

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I am currently using biblatex/biber with 'chem-rsc' style for citing my references in latex. Unfortunately, with this style the date of access is not displayed for @online entries in the bibliography. Now I am trying to redefine the bibliography format for URLs, so that I'd get the following format (german):

online unter URL: >>URL<<, aufgerufen am >>urldate<<

After some research I have patched together the following code from different threads concerning this topic.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[style=chem-rsc]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{references.bib}
@Online{AgIGESTIS,
  institution  = {IFA},
  organization = {IFA},
  urldate    = {2023-01-30},
  title        = {Eintrag zu Silberiodid in der GESTIS-Stoffdatenbank},
  url          = {https://gestis.dguv.de/data?name=122731},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{references.bib}

\NewBibliographyString{available}
\NewBibliographyString{cited}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{%
  available = {online unter URL},
 cited = {aufgerufen am},
}

\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\bibstring{available}\addcolon\space\url{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{#1}

\renewbibmacro*{url+urldate}{%
  \printfield{url}\addcomma\space
  \printtext{\bibstring{cited}}
  \printfield{urldate}
  }
  
\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum\nocite{AgIGESTIS}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

While I'm getting the correct format from this in general, the urldate is not printed. Apparently the `\printfield{urldate}` statemend does not work here. I also tried `\printurldate` or `\printfield{urlday}`, but none of that seemed to return anything. Any idea what I am doing wrong? Is there any other way I get the date displayed?

Comment: urldate is not a "real" field, the data is in urlyear, urlmonth and urlday, you can also use `\printurldate`. But before redefining everything try `\ExecuteBibliographyOptions[online]{url=true}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `urldate` field in a bibliography file is parsed by `biblatex` resp. `biber` into its components `urlyear`, `urlmonth`, `urlday` and various other fields. This is documented in the `biblatex` documentation: for v3.18b (July 12, 2022) see section 4.2.4.3 "Date Component Fields":

```
See table 10 for an overview of how the date fields in bib files are related to the
date fields provided by the style interface.
```

The references table describes all resulting fields you can use in your formatting macros.  Use `\iffieldundef` to test for existing fields.

This allows you to format dates in the most appropriate date format you want.

Thus in your redefined `url+urldate` bib macro you have to replace the line

`\printfield{urldate}`

by

`\printurldate`

and set the date format via options. (Thanks @moewe!)

(If needed you can implement it using low level
`\printfield{urlyear}-\printfield{urlmonth}-\printfield{urlday}`
and adding `\iffieldundef` tests to allow incomplete dates, e.g., without a day.)

Comment: Replacing the line fixed it. Thanks for helping out!

Comment: Please don't say `\printfield{urlyear}-\printfield{urlmonth}-\printfield{urlday}`. Instead use `\printurldate` and set the date format via the options.

Comment: Thanks @moewe - changed my answer accordingly.